# Deploy a Multi-Tenant WebApi with Tenant-Specific Configuration

Tags: octopus-deploy

Is there a way to deploy a single instance multi-tenant aware web api with specific configuration per tenant?

We have an Asp.net Web Api witch identify the tenant by claims inside a JWT but into the web.config are configuration per tenant. Example

```
<configuration>
<appSettings>
...
</appSettings>
<tenants>
   <tenant key="1">
      <add key="key1" value="false" />
   </tenant>
   <tenant key="2">
      <add key="key1" value="value2" />
   </tenant>
</tenants>
</configuration>
```

We dont use multi-tenancy in Octopus becose is only one installation per target but we cant imagine how to store and insert the configuration per tenant.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Full disclosure: I work for Octopus Deploy.

If I understand correctly you have a single binary that serves multiple tenants and `web.config` is used to specify which tenants are served by the application.

If so, then I would recommend splitting your application into 2 Octopus Projects. One which represents application code and one which represents configuration. The configuration Project would use multi tenancy in Octopus to add relevant entries to the web.config for each deployed tenant. This can be done using [a config transformation](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/configuration-files#Configurationfiles-ConfigurationTransformationConfigurationtransforms) or [a custom script](https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-examples/custom-scripts#Customscripts-Standalonescripts).

SO is a public forum so if you would like to share some sensitive information about your project then I would recommend  you reach out to us via https://octopus.com/support.

Regards,

Comment: Hi Pawel, will not be very prone to errors? For every deploy of App Project a deploy of Conf Project **must** be done manually. Thanks for the idea

Comment: I don't think so. First project deploys *only* code so the config stays untouched. The second Project *only* modifies the config.

Comment: With the default directory tree generated by the tentacle the App Project will be installed in a directory like ".../$Enviroment/AppProject/$Version/" witch will be diferent in each deployment. So when AppProject is deployed the web.config inside will be a "vanilla" version without tenant specific configuration. In the interim betwen AppProyect and AppConfig is deployed the app is in a invalid state, thats what i think. My other doubt with this aproach is how i can know where the AppProject was deployed inside AppConfig.

Comment: You can make the path predictable by using https://octopus.com/docs/deployment-process/configuration-files/custom-installation-directory.